# The code within the method 'InitializeComponent' is generated by the designer

Tags: c#, winforms, windows-forms-designer, initializecomponent

> The code within the method 'InitializeComponent' is generated by the designer and should not be manually modified.  Please remove any changes and try opening the designer again.

I am a newbie at this so please bear with me.  I copied and pasted some forms and immediately got this error.  So I logged into the person's computer
who wrote the program, repeated the steps and that did not help.

I changed everything in the new form that said FormA to FormB if you will.  I'm not trying to be vague, but the program is so big I don't even know what to paste in here.

I keep getting issues with Components and or Initialize Components and I don't know what it means. I'm also too new to understand what the other StackOverflow solutions are. I tried deleting the Designer.cs  and that did not help.  It is not a web form.  It's a C# program with a SQL back end.

Here is some of the code. I'm not sure if that helps.  I have 8000 errors. I think it's related to this.

```
public FormA()
    {
        InitializeComponent();
        this.StartPosition = FormStartPosition.CenterScreen;
    }
```

I'm getting errors here too. It's red underlining bool and compoents.Dispose

```
    protected override void Dispose(bool disposing)
    {
        if (disposing && (components != null))
        {
            components.Dispose();
        }
        base.Dispose(disposing);
    }
```

Also I'm getting many errors regarding the FormA. (It's not called that, I'm just using it for clarity.) Ambiguity between FormA.textA and FormA.textA (Yes it's the same, but it compiles just fine with the original version.)

Can anyone help me? Thanks.

Edit: Adding the beginning code for Amy

```
   public partial class FormA : Form
    {

        string dbname = @"SERVER = np:PROD; DATABASE = TEMP; Integrated security = true; Enlist = false";
        string user = Environment.UserName.ToString();
        System.Windows.Forms.Timer tmr = new System.Windows.Forms.Timer();
        System.Windows.Forms.Timer IdleTimer = new System.Windows.Forms.Timer();

        public FormA()
        {
            InitializeComponent();
            this.StartPosition = FormStartPosition.CenterScreen;
        }

        private void FormA_Load(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {
            Application.Idle += new EventHandler(Application_Idle);
            this.KeyPreview = true;
            btnSched.Text = "Edit " + DateTime.Now.ToString("MM/dd/yyyy") + " Schedule";
            calendarRefresh();
            tmr.Interval = 1000;//ticks every 1 second
            tmr.Tick += new EventHandler(tmr_Tick);
            tmr.Start();
            loadCurrentlyDisplayed();
            createUser();
            refreshUsers();
            loadNotes();
        }
```

After this it's just function after function doing various things.  I can add more, but I don't know how much room I have.

Comment: Please add your entire class to the question.  It sounds like you're attempting to declare methods outside of a class.

Comment: Copy the actual files: formA.cs, formA.Designer.cs, and formA.resx and then add the formA.cs into your project solution (the other files will automatically come with it).

Comment: Make sure your previous attempts have been removed.

Comment: I copied all the files. I did not rename them. I dragged them in from the folder to the Solution Explorer. It says two output file names resolved to the same output path obj\debug\FormA.rescources.  I'm trying to figure out how to fix that now.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

> The code within the method 'InitializeComponent' is generated by the
>   designer and should not be manually modified. Please remove any
>   changes and try opening the designer again.

Generated code shouldn't be modified, because manual changes will be discarded. This should really be a warning, but it does highlight the issue before you get too deep.

There are a few solutions:

- Delete the modified designer files(*.g.cs) and rebuild. This should cause VS to regenerate them. This usually works, but does fail from time to time. Designer files won't be visible from the solution explorer unless manually added, you'll have to delete them from the file browser. By default they're in the obj folder of the project.
- If you haven't saved, closed, and re-opened the solution, you should be able to undo all changes made to the designer file.
- Copy all but the designer code to a scratchpad, delete the form, recreate it, and inject the copied code where appropriate.

> I'm getting errors here too. It's red underlining bool and
>   components.Dispose

This suggests Dispose isn't a method of whatever class `components` is. Until you post its type we can't be of much help with this.

> Also I'm getting many errors regarding the FormA. (It's not called
>   that, I'm just using it for clarity.) Ambiguity between FormA.textA
>   and FormA.textA (Yes it's the same, but it compiles just fine with the
>   original version.)

This is most likely related to the designer file issue. Try the solutions at the beginning of this answer. If that doesn't fix it, the form code(i.e. FormA.cs) must have duplicate fields. Ensure that the designer file hasn't been modified and no duplicate field names exist in the form code.

Comment: Thanks. I am trying to copy 4 forms. I deleted 12 .cs files.  Now it's saying it can't find them.  Unable to create a manifest rescoure name for FormB.resx. Could not find the file \\file directory\FormB.cs  If I just delete the .cs files from the original form, it gives me the same error.   I'm sorry, I don't understand your second and third bullets.

Comment: If you haven't permanently deleted the .cs files, recycle them from the bin and reopen the solution. After making backups of your form code, use the solution explorer to delete each form that's causing problems. That will get rid of any designer or resx files associated with each form without having to dig around the project folder manually.

Comment: So delete FormA.cs from the Solution Explorer?  I did that and it's saying cannot find file C:\blah blah\FormA.cs  So I closed and reopened it and it compiled without error.  However FormA is gone. So I published and it says The type or namespace FormA  could not be found.  Are you missing a using directive or assembly reference?   It's gone. It's gone in the folder as well. Every trace of all four files are gone (I have backups.) But clearly I am missing something.  Thank you.

Comment: Yes, based on my 3rd point. When all else fails you can delete a form from the solution explorer and recreate it from a backup.

Comment: Thanks. I got it to work.  I had to start over.  I copied and pasted all the files like you said and put them into a separate folder. Then I renamed them.  Then I dragged and dropped them into the solution explorer.  I closed and reopened the app and built and published it and it works. I might have forgotten something. I've taken a lot of cold meds today.  But anyways thank you. I understand now and will up vote you and mark as answered and will try to do that with the other poster too as they helped. Thanks again.